# Correlate is to Correlation as X is to Causation

Tags: verbs, antonyms

When *A* is correlated with *B*, it means *A* shares 1 or more properties with *B*.¹

On the other hand, if *A* causes *B*, it means there's a causation between them.²

What I would like to know is the word that fills in the blank, as follows:

`The storm clouds were correlated with the death of my loved one because she died within 5 minutes of them appearing. But the dagger in her back was __________ with the tragedy because it was found to cause fatal blood loss.`

In other words, what is the verb form of *causation*? I know *cause* fits, but that doesn't always work. For instance, in a chain of events *A, B, C, D...* and so forth, unless I set two different definitions for the verb, *cause*, I won't necessarily be able to know whether I'm talking about what Element *F* did to Element *G* or about the number of *direct causal relationships* there are among some number of these elements.

I looked on the OED (click small insert to enlarge):

[image: OED Screenshot]

and saw that *causate* might be the case, but found it's not because I'm not looking for a word that means "to cause", merely "to have a causal relationship with".

Basically, I want to know the opposite of the phrase, *is correlated with*.

---

¹ For example, if a leaf is green and so is your car, they are correlated because they both share the same colour property. If you went to the store at the same time a storm happened, your trip to the store would correlate with the storm because their time value would be identical.

(Of course, as the trip to the store did not cause or imply the coming of the storm, nor had the leaf being green caused or implied your car to be green, this correlation does not imply a causation between them.)

² Strictly formulated, it would be that a change in 1 or more properties in *A* directly produces a change in 1 or more properties in *B*.

Comment: Please give an example of something that is in a causal relationship with something else, but does not cause it.

Comment: Welcome to ELU, Sarah. Linguistically, the **analogy** of your title is completed with the verb *caus[at]e*. Clearly, that is inconsistent with the internal contradictions of your question and comments. It seems strange to me that you would berate others for their sincere attempts to help you. Examining and testing semantics one of the reasons we post comments and answers here, so we don't consider that a waste of time. You may not be ready to appreciate the semantics until you have grasped the fundamental logical and scientific concepts that befuddle you.

Comment: @ScotM: You're right that my behaviour it was rude of me. I feel bad about it and I sincerely apologise for all of it. I got defencive and it was uncalled for. I guess I felt kind of attacked, to some degree, like the others thought I was stupid or something for supposedly not knowing something like this.

Also, upon reëxamining my question, I feel my wording could have been a lot better. So in light of this, I'll rephrase it, hopefully making it clearer what exactly I'm asking.

Comment: @phoog: Please note that when I said *causal relationship*, I wasn't saying it in the sense that A causes B; I was saying it in the sense that some group of elements in a given system is interacting, directly or indirectly, in some way, through cause-and-effect processes. That is it. (1/3)

Comment: So, for example, if I hit a hammer on a plank of wood, some of its momentum will transfer into the wood upon impact. Then, as the momentum flows through the wood, the vibrations will propagate from one cubic centimetre of said wood to the next for however long. Each step in this causal chain of events, *A, B, C, D...* and so forth, is an element in this causal system. (2/3).

Comment: Because *A* causes *B*, I can say that A directly affected B. The same could be said of B unto C, and so forth. However, because A directly affected B, and B consequently then directly affected C, then it must be acknowledged that A **indirectly** affected C. (3/3)

Comment: In generic usage, *correlation* denotes any association between variables in any dimension of time, space, matter or energy: leaf and car **associate** in color with "irrelevant" causal relationship, clouds and death of a loved one **associate** in time (and perhaps space to a local observer) with "irrelevant" causal relationship, but the knife and death of a loved one **associate** in time, space and body with "significant" causal relationship. These *associations* and *causes* generate complex permutations of "correlation" that tend to **confound** the semantic goal of your analogy.

Comment: @SarahofGaia but does "cause" necessarily imply "directly"?  When one presses an electric doorbell button, one causes a doorbell to ring, but the mechanism is indirect: pressing the button causes a switch to close, which causes electricity to flow through a circuit, which causes an electromagnet to be energized, which causes a steel rod to strike a tuned steel bar, which makes waves in the air, which travel into a resonating chamber, which amplifies the waves.

Answer (score 1):

There are a least three questions here, one of which should be posted on Philosophy SE.  Yet, in case this answers the question you are asking, here is a list of verbs in order of intensity describing a causal relationship between A and B.

A influences B
supports
contributes to
undelies,
substantiates,
instigates
causes.

Comment: Except all these (except for "undelies"; I couldn't find any definition for that) implies directionality. I'm looking for one that is opposite of "correlated with". Instead of "A is correlated with B", it'd be "A is [...] with B". Just because A is correlated with B doesn't mean that B can't be correlated with A. I'm looking for a word that denotes a nondirectionally specific causal interaction.

Comment: Also, how in the *world* is my question philosophical? I'm looking for a word here, not to argue semantics.

Comment: @SarahofGaia. I think your question is valuable and I therefore upvoted it. 'Undelies' is a typo for underlies, apologies. As Vladkornea's linked page shows, correlation does not imply causation: therefore causation should not be assumed. 'Non-causal correlation' is what you are rejecting; 'causal correlation' is probably the phrase you are looking for. Good luck with your search.

Comment: I'm not looking for a phrase, but a word, specifically a verb. And no, my wording just bad. I know the difference between causality and correlation.

Comment: "...but the dagger in her back *effected* the tragedy, because..."  ?? I'll keep looking.

Comment: No, it has to be in the form of "A *was* ______ with B"

Comment: I'm not looking for the verb that says what A did to the B but rather says that "A has a relationship with B such that said relation is causal rather than correlative".