# Correlated but not....?

Tags: single-word-requests

@SarahofGaia was asking a similar question in 2015 but it doesn't seem to have been answered despite the feed being closed.

"Relationships between nodes vary. Those that are correlated but not______ are represented here..."

I'm looking for a single word that signifies that multiple nodes are related but not by way of cause and effect.

Thanks!

Comment: Please link the related question asked by @sarahofgaia.

Answer (score 3):

At the risk of picking the bones of [SarahofGaia's question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/259550/26083), 
***causally related*** and ***causally linked*** seem to be what you want:

> ***[causal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/causal):***
>
>   relating to or showing the cause of something  / 
>     making something happen : causing something

Comment: Hi @scott, thanks for your response. Causally related/linked will work. Just to clarify, there isn't a single word to express this?

Comment: I can't think of one.  Let's give the community a couple of days and see whether they come up with anything.

Comment: @SJK "Causal" is a single word and personally I think this is the best answer. Correlation/Causation are common words in statistics. If your audience understands stats then "causal" will be perfectly clear. To add, "causally related/linked" is redundant, as "causal" already implies a relationship.

Comment: @ChristopherD: So you believe that the single word "causal" is appropriate in contexts like "Diet and health are causal." or "Tobacco use and cancer are causal."?

Comment: @scott, in the context of statistics, yes. It's more often termed "causality" in stats so I would reword "...but do not represent causality." But I do think "causal" would be acceptable, just a bit awkward.

Comment: @SJK ~ https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/causational